# Django makemessages duplicates translation

Tags: python, django

I have existing .po file, But I am still building my project so new translation strings are added and some of already added one are changing places.

To update my .po file I am running

```
django-admin makemessages -l en
```

When I open the file I see that the same translation is duplicated many times:

```
#: _templates/admin-users/base/partials/sidebar.html:38
msgid "main-nav-guests"
msgstr "Guests"


#: _templates/admin-users/base/partials/sidebar.html:58
#, fuzzy
#| msgid "main-nav-guests"
msgid "main-nav-event-settings"
msgstr "Guests"

#: _templates/admin-users/base/partials/sidebar.html:101
#, fuzzy
#| msgid "main-nav-guests"
msgid "main-nav-events"
msgstr "Guests"

#: _templates/admin-users/base/partials/sidebar.html:106
#, fuzzy
#| msgid "main-nav-guests"
msgid "main-nav-account-settings"
msgstr "Guests"
```

My Django Version is 1.9.5

How can I fix that ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

`makemessages` always tries to be smart. If you already have a translation for `'main-nav-guests'` (on a side note, what are you translating here: English-English?) and add other messages that resemble that `msgid`, they will receive the same `msgstr` as the existing one, but be marked with those `fuzzy` comments:

```
#, fuzzy
#| msgid "main-nav-guests"
```

that indicate that this is a) auto-generated by fuzzy msgid-matching and b) it used the translation of the `"main-nav-guests"` `msgid`.

What  I usually do after each `makemessages`, is to search the `django.po` for empty `msgstr` and `'fuzzy'` translations. Then I fill the empty and correct the fuzzy ones if necessary which includes removing the two comment lines from above. Then, everything should be ready to go.

Adding some sort of `--no-fuzzy` option for `makemessages` [was suggested and declined](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10852).

Comment: Is it possible to run it without the fuzzy msgs... I don't need that I need only the translation string once